# How to get dropdownlist value as number to SQL command in ASP

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, t-sql

I have a dropdown list:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>30</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="100000">All</asp:ListItem>
```

and the code-behind is:

```
Private Sub BindAllEmployee()
    Dim CS As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim sNumber As String = DropDownList1.SelectedValue
    Dim iNumber As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(sNumber)
    Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(CS)

        Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT TOP '" + iNumber + "' [EmployeeID], [EmployeeCode], [EmployeeName], [Position], [HireDate] FROM [Employee] ORDER BY [EmployeeID] DESC", con)

            Using sda As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                Dim dte As DataTable = New DataTable()
                sda.Fill(dte)
                GridView1.DataSource = dte
                GridView1.DataBind()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

I got an error :

> Conversion from string "SELECT TOP '" to type 'Double' is not valid

Answer (score 0):

The argument to TOP should not be quoted. So you could try

```
"SELECT TOP " + iNumber + " [EmployeeID] ...
```

instead.

But also there's actually no need to convert `sNumber` to an integer, because when you include it in the SqlCommand it will just need to be converted back to a string again (since the SQL command text is one big string).

So actually

```
"SELECT TOP " + sNumber + " [EmployeeID] ...
```

would make a bit more sense.

So here's a final version which I think will work better:

```
Private Sub BindAllEmployee()
    Dim CS As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim sNumber As String = DropDownList1.SelectedValue

    Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(CS)
        Dim sql as String = "SELECT TOP" + sNumber + " [EmployeeID], [EmployeeCode], [EmployeeName], [Position], [HireDate] FROM [Employee] ORDER BY [EmployeeID] DESC"

        Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql , con)

            Using sda As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                Dim dte As DataTable = New DataTable()
                sda.Fill(dte)
                GridView1.DataSource = dte
                GridView1.DataBind()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the query string:

```
New SqlCommand("SELECT TOP " + iNumber.ToString() + " [EmployeeID], [EmployeeCode], [EmployeeName], [Position], [HireDate] FROM [Employee] ORDER BY [EmployeeID] DESC", con)
```

You have to cast *iNumber* to string to concatenate it and remove the single quotes as already suggested.

Ore use directly *sNumber*:

```
New SqlCommand("SELECT TOP " + sNumber + " [EmployeeID], [EmployeeCode], [EmployeeName], [Position], [HireDate] FROM [Employee] ORDER BY [EmployeeID] DESC", con)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is some confusion with the + sign for concatenation.  I get the error with Option Strict on. The compiler is attempting to add (arithmetic add) "SELECT TOP" to the Integer When I change the + to and & ampersand which is the concatenation symbol in vb.net that error disappears. Also remover the single quotes.

There is no need to change the drop down value to a number. It is being used in a string so to use string concatenation a string is appropriate. If you use a string the compiler will interpret the + sign as a concatenation operator but it is best to always use & for this.

Dimension the DataTable outside of the Using blocks. This way you can use it after the connection is closed to fill the grid. Get the connection closed as soon as possible.

```
Private Sub BindAllEmployee()
    Dim dte As DataTable = New DataTable()
    Dim CS As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim sNumber As String = DropDownList1.SelectedValue
    Using con As New SqlConnection(CS)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT TOP " & sNumber & " [EmployeeID], [EmployeeCode], [EmployeeName], [Position], [HireDate] FROM [Employee] ORDER BY [EmployeeID] DESC", con)
            dte.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using
    GridView1.DataSource = dte
    GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub
```